# Wheres my posts object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I think I am doing this wrong in backbone, So I have a collection, model and route as such:

**Route**

```
AisisWriter.Collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: AisisWriter.Models.Post,
  // Build the url based on blog id.
  url: function() {
    url = '/api/v1/blogs/' + AisisWriter.blog_id + '/posts/'
    return url;
  }
});
```

**Collection**

```
AisisWriter.Routers.Posts = Backbone.Router.extend({

  posts: null,

  routes : {
      '': 'index'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    var writer_posts = new AisisWriter.Collections.Posts();
    this.posts = writer_posts.fetch();
  },

  index: function() {
    console.log(AisisWriter.blog_id, this.posts);
  }

});
```

**Model**

```
AisisWriter.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {},

  getTitle: function() {
    return this.get('title');
  },

  getContent: function() {
    return this.get('content');
  },

  getTags: function() {
    return this.get('tag_names');
  },

  getCategories: function() {
    return this.get('category_names');
  },

  getComments: function() {
    return this.get('comments');
  },

});
```

When the collections index route executes, I get the following back:

`Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

Note: The above is a console output of a non expanded object.

This ... I guess what I would or should expect, accept I assumed I would be getting back my posts object because doing `this.posts.getTitle()` doesn't work.

So what am I doing wrong in terms of getting my posts object back? Inside this giant object I see a ResponseJSON object that contains my json object - I want that so I can do `this.posts.getTitle()`;

Comment: (1) `x.fetch()` is an AJAX call so you have to wait for the server to respond before you'll have anything useful. (2) `x.fetch()` populates `x` and returns a `jqXHR`, it doesn't return a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is doublicate:
[Why can I not use this.posts out side the success function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935782/why-can-i-not-use-this-posts-out-side-the-success-function)

So as I adviced to you. If you want to get access to this.posts you should just add the observer to your collection in the initialize function:

```
this.listenTo(this.writer_posts, 'reset', this.test);
```

Thats I call the Backbone way.

On the other hand it's dificult to understand what you wanna do. For example you're trying to get title from the Collection...

```
var writer_posts = new AisisWriter.Collections.Posts();
this.posts = writer_posts.fetch();
```

and then

```
this.posts.getTitle()
```

It doesn't work, because it is Collection. And you don't need to create separate methods for getting title, tag and so on from your Model. You can get access to the title directly:

```
this.model.get('title');
```

or

```
this.model.toJSON().title;
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch() is an asynchromous call, so you need to wait for the response from the server. Put the assignment to "posts" in the success handler:

```
var that;

AisisWriter.Routers.Posts = Backbone.Router.extend({

  posts: null,

  routes : {
      '': 'index'
  },

  initialize: function() {
  },

  index: function() {
    that = this;
    var writer_posts = new AisisWriter.Collections.Posts();
    writer_posts.fetch({
        reset: true,
        success: function (collection, response, options) {
            console.log(AisisWriter.blog_id, collection);
            that.posts = collection;
        },
        error: function (collection, response, options) {

        }
    });

  }

});
```