# Why can I not use this.posts out side the success function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Maybe I am not understanding scoping but in the following:

```
AisisWriter.Routers.Posts = Backbone.Router.extend({

  writer_posts: null,

  posts: null,

  routes : {
      '': 'index'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.writer_posts = new AisisWriter.Collections.Posts();
  },

  index: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.writer_posts.fetch({
      reset: true,
      success: function(collection, response, options){
        this.posts = collection;
        console.log(this.posts);
      }
    });

    console.log(self.posts)
  }

});
```

inside the `success: function(){}` the `this.posts` console log has two posts in it. it looks like:

`child {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}`

But when I try and use `this.posts` out side the fetch call, it returns null. Why is that? Is `this` not scoped properly? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `this.posts` is not yet populated by the time you try to log it. this is AJAX, you know..

Comment: See the updated post, I have tried assigning this to the var self and doing it that way still doesn't work

Comment: AJAX is Asynchronous. you **cannot** *effectively* use .posts outside of the success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not being able to get access to your this.posts only because it is executed sooner than you get the response. You even don't have to save 'this' in the self variable. To check it just add in the initialize function this line:

```
this.listenTo(this.writer_posts, 'reset', this.test);
```

And then create test function:

```
test: function() { console.log(this.posts); }
```

As you will see collection is saved properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since your fetch might take time to get into success promise the next line is getting executed sooner before that.

```
index: function() {
var self = this;
this.writer_posts.fetch({
  reset: true,
  success: function(collection, response, options){
    //write your callback function inside the success
    //self.afterSuccess(collection);
  }
 });
 },
```

You can pass the parameters for the function and fetch it.

```
afterSuccess: function(collection) {
   console.log("the collection has"+JSON.stringify(collection));
}
```

Comment: this.posts = collection; can you give a try on this.Change it to self.posts = collection;

Comment: updated the answer please try this out.See your console which line is getting executed first .